# How to define a function using jQuery code in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function

I found several questions about how to declare regular JS functions within jQuery. But how to define a *jQuery function* within "jQuery(function ()" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
jQuery.fn.foo = function() {
  return 'bar';
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Where should I declare the "foo" function? How/where to call it?